# Convert Italic XML Tags into WordML Tags II

Tags: xml, xslt, wordml

I'm several WEEKS old inhabiting these XSL WordML XML "worlds", and, im *really* dissapointed on the way the so called 'XSLT Processor' handle things.

Regarding an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234215/xml-to-wordml-using-xslt-1-0-replace-html-tags-within-xml-content-with-wordml), the purpose is (if -we still- can call it simple) to transform Light Word XML files into well-formed WordML files.

I'm sorry for the extended question, but i guess there is no other way to explain.

I have the following **XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<body>
    <heading>
        This is the <bold><italic>standard</italic> text</bold> run.
    </heading>
    <copyright/>
</body>
```

The purpose is formatting, separately as per a WordML document, each *paragraph* and *character* style:

- WordML *paragraph* styles element are 'normal' and 'heading' (here only heading), and are embraced by 'w:p' tags
- WordML *character run* styles elements are 'italic', 'bold' and 'underline' (here only italic and bold), and are embraced by 'w:r' tags
- WordML *text* nodes are embraced by 'w:t' tags

So, the expected **WordML document** output is the following:

```
<w:wordDocument xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" 
    xml:space="preserve">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading"/></w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>This is the </w:t>
                <w:rPr><w:b w:val="on"/></w:rPr>
                <w:rPr><w:i w:val="on"/></w:rPr>
                <w:t>standard </w:t>
                <w:rPr><w:i w:val="off"/></w:rPr>
                <w:t>text </w:t>
                <w:rPr><w:b w:val="off"/></w:rPr>
                <w:t>run.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Using the following **XSL Template File** (to be corrected by your feedback):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"
    xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
            xml:space="preserve">
            <w:body>
                <xsl:apply-templates match="normal|heading"/>
            </w:body>
        </w:wordDocument>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="heading">
            <w:p>     
            <w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading"/></w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <xsl:apply-templates match="italic|bold"/>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="heading"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <w:rPr><w:b w:val="on"/></w:rPr>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="text()"/>
        <w:rPr><w:b w:val="off"/></w:rPr>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="italic|bold"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="italic">
        <w:rPr><w:i w:val="on"/></w:rPr>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="text()"/>
        <w:rPr><w:i w:val="off"/></w:rPr>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="italic|bold"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <w:t><xsl:value-of select="."/></w:t>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

They simply *dont work*, the XSLT Processor  completely omits the "match" sentence. Note the double apply-template is necessary, because there is different nesting location of templates according the type of paragraph - character content.

The usual mistaken results is obtain this kind of content inside the **WordML document**:

```
    ...
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>run.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>    

    <w:t>This is </w:t>
    ...
```

which is perfectly legal XML, but totally unacceptable, having a text outside any paragraph, making the WordML document corrupt. Besides, templates are logically correct, if those apply-template & match would really do their proper job.

Please, any suggestion (including throwing all these 'templates' and starting back in any standard language program) are acceptable.

Comment: I think in order for this to be figure-out-able you'll need to provide a more complete sample of the output you're getting (e.g. show us the `<w:body>` element), and a more complete sample of your XSLT. As it is, what you're showing doesn't match the output.

Comment: Thanks LarsH, i've included complete samples for the XSL stylesheet, the input and the desired output....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised you are not getting syntax errors, because the following XSLT is invalid

```
 <xsl:apply-templates match="italic|bold"/>
```

The **match** attribute is not valid of **xsl:apply-templates**. It should be **select**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="italic|bold"/>
```

I think the main issue is with your **bold** and **italic** templates

```
<xsl:template match="bold">
     <w:rPr><w:b w:val="on"/></w:rPr>
     <xsl:apply-templates match="text()"/>
     <w:rPr><w:b w:val="off"/></w:rPr>
     <xsl:apply-templates match="italic|bold"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As well as using **match** instead of **select**, you are looking for **italic** or **bold** elements after you have closed of the **w:b** element. What you really need to be doing is, is this.

```
<xsl:template match="bold"> 
   <w:rPr>
      <w:b w:val="on"/>
   </w:rPr>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
   <w:rPr>
      <w:b w:val="off"/>
   </w:rPr>
</xsl:template>
```

So, instead of explicitly searching for certain elements, search of any elements, and have other templates to handle the matching.

Here is the full XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xml:space="preserve"> 
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="body"> 
      <w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve"> 
         <w:body> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="normal|heading"/>
         </w:body>
      </w:wordDocument>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="heading"> 
      <w:p> 
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading"/>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r> 
            <xsl:apply-templates />
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="bold"> 
      <w:rPr>
         <w:b w:val="on"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <w:rPr>
         <w:b w:val="off"/>
      </w:rPr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="italic"> 
      <w:rPr>
         <w:i w:val="on"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <w:rPr>
         <w:i w:val="off"/>
      </w:rPr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()"> 
      <w:t>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </w:t>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<w:wordDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
   <w:body> 
      <w:p> 
         <w:pPr> 
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading"/>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r> 
            <w:t> This is the </w:t>
            <w:rPr> 
               <w:b w:val="on"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:rPr> 
               <w:i w:val="on"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t> standard </w:t>
            <w:rPr> 
               <w:i w:val="off"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t> text </w:t>
            <w:rPr> 
               <w:b w:val="off"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t> run. </w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
   </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Isn't it necessary to separate this in different runs? „val="off"" doesn't work for me. It looks like this: This is the **_standard text run_**.